# Set CuteEditor EnableStripIframeTags property from configuration

Tags: cuteeditor

I've been working on an existing project that uses CuteEditor control.
I've found out that in order to enable iframe tag, I need to add the property `EnableStripIframeTags` and set it to false. However, the CuteEditor control appears in a lot of pages.

Is there an option to set `EnableStripIframeTags` from the CuteEditor's config files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think thats possible. My solution would be to create a method which would set the property and call it from each page.

There are usually several other properties that need to be changed which also could be added to that method.

```
public void initialiseEditor(CuteEditor.Editor editor) {

        editor.EnableStripIframeTags = true;
        editor.EnableStripScriptTags = true;
        editor.EnableStripStyleTagsCodeInjection = true;

}
```